# Old kernel in grub and /boot but not uninstallable

Tags: 12.04, grub2, kernel, uninstall

I have kernel 2.6.38 still visible in the grub menu and I see

```
abi-2.6.38-11-generic
config-2.6.38-11-generic
initrd.img-2.6.38-11-generic
vmlinuz-2.6.38-11-generic
```

(among the respective files for the recent kernel) in `/boot`.

**But** when I try to find the package with dpkg I don't see it:

```
$ dpkg -l | grep linux-image
2338:rc  linux-image-3.0.0-14-generic     3.0.0-14.23    Linux kernel image for version 3.0.0 on x86/x86_64
2339:rc  linux-image-3.0.0-15-generic     3.0.0-15.26    Linux kernel image for version 3.0.0 on x86/x86_64
2340:rc  linux-image-3.0.0-16-generic     3.0.0-16.29    Linux kernel image for version 3.0.0 on x86/x86_64
2341:ii  linux-image-3.2.0-29-generic     3.2.0-29.46    Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
2342:ii  linux-image-generic              3.2.0.29.31    Generic Linux kernel image
```

**How can I remove these old kernel files safely?**

I am running Ubuntu 12.04, `uname -a` reads

```
Linux XYZ 3.2.0-29-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 27 17:03:23 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can safely remove any file/directory having `2.6.38-11` in their names, as this is not your running kernel anymore. This kernel must have been installed during a precedent Ubuntu install.

They should normally belong to a package, but as they are not, you should remove them manually.

To know what type of files are installed with a kernel, you can do `dpkg -L linux-image-3.2.0-29-generic | less`

Then you can remove all the files/directories listed by `ls -1d /{boot,lib/modules,lib/firmware,usr/share/doc}/*2.6.38-11*`

Then run `sudo update-grub`, it should purge the grub entry. If not, check the content of `/etc/grub.d`